# Custom ToolStrip renderer in C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli, renderer, toolstrip

I want to make a custom renderer for ToolStrip, but all the manuals and guides are written in C#.

Here is an example https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29497/Custom-Rendering-for-the-ToolStrip-MenuStrip-and-S

I tried porting this code to C++, but I didn't really succeed, since I don't really understand C#.

How to do it in C++/CLI?

Comment: You do it in C++/CLI the exact same way you do in C#.  It doesn't sound like you really made an attempt.  If you have a question about a particular short snippet of C# that uses a feature C++ doesn't have, and searching came up with nothing, then ask about that small snippet.

Comment: Also note that article is terrible.  You shouldn't ever add your own classes inside the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace, or anywhere else inside `System.*` or `Microsoft.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's if anyone needs my solution to the problem...

CustomColorTable.h

```
namespace YourNamespace
{
    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;
    public ref class CustomColorTable : public System::Windows::Forms::ProfessionalColorTable {
    public:
        Color _color = Color::DeepPink;
    public:
        property Color MenuBorder
        {
        public: virtual Color get() override
        {
            return _color;
        };
        };
    public:
        property Color MenuItemBorder
        {
        public: virtual Color get() override
        {
            return _color;
        };
        };
    public:
        property Color MenuItemPressedGradientBegin
        {
        public: virtual Color get() override
        {
            return _color;
        };
        };
    public:
        property Color MenuItemPressedGradientEnd
        {
        public: virtual Color get() override
        {
            return _color;
        };
        };
    public:
        property Color MenuItemPressedGradientMiddle
        {
        public: virtual Color get() override
        {
            return _color;
        };
        };
    public:
        property Color MenuItemSelected
        {
        public: virtual Color get() override
        {
            return _color;
        };
        };
    public:
        property Color MenuItemSelectedGradientBegin
        {
        public: virtual Color get() override
        {
            return _color;
        };
        };
    public:
        property Color MenuItemSelectedGradientEnd
        {
        public: virtual Color get() override
        {
            return _color;
        };
        };
    public:
        property Color MenuStripGradientBegin
        {
        public: virtual Color get() override
        {
            return _color;
        };
        };
    public:
        property Color MenuStripGradientEnd
        {
        public: virtual Color get() override
        {
            return _color;
        };
        };
    };
}
```

In your form with MenuStrip

```
#include "CustomColorTable.h"

namespace YourNamespace 
{
    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;
    using namespace System::Resources;
    public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        Form1(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this->MenuStrip1->RenderMode = System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripRenderMode::System;
            this->MenuStrip1->Renderer = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripProfessionalRenderer(gcnew CustomColorTable()));
...
```

You can also do this for ToolStrip, you just need to change the names of the properties in CustomColorTable.h

Names of the properties can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-Ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.professionalcolors?view=windowsdesktop-6.0&viewFallbackFrom=net-5.0)